# Html and Css files not linking

Tags: html, css

I have the following css and html files.

```css
html, body, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins,
kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol,
ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot,
th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption,
figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time,
mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif
}

#tab-bar {
    background: #050405;
    border-bottom: 1px #441d22 solid;
    position: relative;
}

/* Clearfix to stop our floats escaping */
#tab:before, #tab-bar:after {
    content: "\0020";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#tab-bar:active {
    clear: both;
}

/* Float our three list items so they're evenly spaced */
#tab-bar li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
}

/* Set a elements as blocks */
#tab a {
    color: #cdcdcd;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.875em; /* 12px / 14px */
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 4.583em; /* 55px / 12px */
    margin: 0 0.833em; /* 10px / 12px*/
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 1.428em; /* 6px / 14px */
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}​
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IEMobile 7]><html class="no-js iem7"><[endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)]]><!-->html class="no-js">!--<![endif]-->
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>StarTrackr</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="screen.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="tab-bar" class="page-spots">
        <li id="tab-spots">
            <a href="#">Spots</a>
        </li>
        <li id="tab-sighting">
            <a href="#">Add a sighting</a>
        </li>
        <li id="tab-stars">
            <a href="#">Stars</a>
        </li>
    </ul><!--#tab-bar -->
</body>
</html>​
```

When I run this, instead of getting an unordered list with each list item styled according to the css, I get the three list items with no styling(no background colors, margins ...etc).

What is the problem?

Again, thanks for any help

Comment: are screen.css and html file in same directory?

Comment: how does your root look like?

Comment: Are you sure there's no styling? I think the background color isn't showing because the `<li>` elements are floated, leaving the `<ul>` without any height. The margins seem to be applied to `#tab a`, which I don't see in your HTML. It would be helpful to describe each other issue in detail.

Comment: Yes they are in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

1. Check whether screen.css is in the same folder as the html file
2. Clear Browser Cache

Comment: For clearing cache you should use a plugin like "Web Developer".
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-developer/bfbameneiokkgbdmiekhjnmfkcnldhhm

Comment: Or get used to using F5 a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add float and width to your tab-bar element.

```
#tab-bar {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #050405;
    border-bottom: 1px #441d22 solid;
    position: relative;
}
```

Also, you're missing a semicolon:

```
body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

[Here's jfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a7ama9ud/)

Answer (score 0):

After adding your code I am sorry but I could not get it to work. I think you are looking for something like this. If not then please dismiss this answer. If you need further assistance please let me know.

```css
html, body, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
blockquote, pre, abbr, address, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins,
kbd, q, samp, small, strong, sub, sup, var, b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol,
ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot,
th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption,
figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary, time,
mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    outline: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: transparent;
}
body {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #050405;
  border-bottom: 2px #ccc solid; /*here you can see the border bottom, I added a red to visually see it*/
}

.container a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
}

.container a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #ccc;
 color: #333;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#sample">Sample</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Spots</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">This is a long name even longer</a>
      <a href="#">Medium name</a>
      <a href="#">Short</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Add a Sighting</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Stars</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <a href="#sample">Sample 2</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  Great suggestions.  It turned out to be the section dealing with tab a elements. It should be tab-bar a